# How to call a function from a particular file in perl?

Tags: file, perl, module

I want to call a function in a particular file by taking filename as input.the mainfile is the argument of the function call.the mainfile changes everytime, func1 remains constant.

```
mainfile
{
    func1()
    {
      .....
      .....
    }

    basefile::func1(mainfile.pm);
}

basefile.pm
{
    func1()
    {
       mainfile::func1();   
    }
}
```

Comment: The syntax you show is not Perl.

Comment: Please show valid Perl code. See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are in search of the [`package`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#package) directive. The `package` call in

```
# basefile.pm
package basefile;
sub func1 { ... }
```

will add the subroutine `func1` in the `basefile` namespace, and make it accessible in any other package under the symbol `basefile::func1`.

For the call from `basefile::func1` to `mainfile::func1` to work, there will need to be a subroutine called `func1` defined in the `mainfile` namespace. You can use a `package` statement in your `mainfile` script

```
# mainfile.pl
package mainfile;
use basefile;
sub func1 { ... }
```

or you can declare a subroutine into a particular namespace by using a fully-qualified subroutine name

```
# mainfile.pl
use basefile;
sub mainfile::func1 { ... }
```

Comment: Also see [perlmod](https://perldoc.pl/perlmod#Perl-Modules) for details on how Perl modules work.

Comment: how can call a function in the module by using variable module name?

Comment: how can call a function in the module by using variable module name?